# Execute some instructions before and after a block is executed

Tags: c++, block, c-preprocessor, auto

I need a syntax that allows me to launch a block of code with a previous initialization of some variables, and after the block of code is executed I need to execute some code to deallocate some other variables.
So the code written inside the block should be executed in the middle of some other operations.

Here is what I got:

```
#define application(block) new Application(&argc, argv); auto __code= []() block ; __code(); mainApplication->launch()
```

The code that you see just initializes an application (a C++ object), so I use it this way:

```
application({
    < write the code >
});
```

This way I am sure that the application is always initialized, and launched after the block.
But I wonder if there is a way to keep away the round parenthesis, so that I can write it this way:

```
application{
    < write the code >
};
```

Also this way works but it should make the syntax lighter.

Comment: That's some pretty horrible macro abuse?

Comment: if you want a syntax different than that of c++, why don't you use other language? e.g. you can write your own translator from your syntax into c++. abusing the pretty weak c++ macro capabilities is perhaps an improper way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide for-loops in a macro to achieve this.

A call to this macro, followed by a block (or single statement), will insert the declaration `decl` with that block as its scope, and evaluate `preexpr` before and `postexpr` after the block:

```
#define LET(decl, preexpr, postexpr) \
    for (int _loop = 1; _loop;) \
        for (decl; _loop && (preexpr, 1); postexpr, _loop = 0)
```

This is C but should work in C++ too; of course, using macros is usually considered to be bad C++ style. The `_loop` variable and the loops should be optimized away by a good compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Invert the problem. Pass an object with the relevant variables, to the code. Let each variable's destructor clean up.